# Plots of each DF column show the same Title (instead of the specific DF column name)

Tags: r, plot, sapply, density-plot

**Hi all!.**

The R code below,
works great to display 4 plots,
one plot for each *numeric* column
in the iris DF.
And that's exactly the plots i need.

*Problem is*,
all 4 plots (one for each column),
have the same default Title at the top:
**Histogram of x**

...instead of a plot Title at the top,
for each *specific* DF column name:
**Histogram of Sepal.Length**
**Histogram of Sepal.Width**,
etc.

Here's the R code:

```
 f <- function(x){
      c( hist(x, freq = FALSE ), 
        lines(density(x)) )
    }
  sapply(iris[1:4], f) # where "f" is the FX f/above!.
```

What R-code am I missing?.
Help, please!...

**SFer --

latest version of R, Rstudio,
Ubuntu LINUX 20.04.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
f <- function(data, colname){
  hist(data[,colname], freq = FALSE, 
       main = paste("Histogram of", colname),
       xlab = colname) 
  lines(density(data[,colname]))
}

sapply(names(iris)[1:4], function(x) f(iris, x))
```

[image]